# How to show a error message when wrong file uploaded other than(jpeg) in ajax_uploadfile asp.net using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET ajax_uploadfile here I need to show a error message I had given `AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png"`

Here is my code:

```
 <asp:AjaxFileUpload runat="server"  ThrobberID="Throbber"
        ID="upFile" AllowedFileTypes="pdf" Onchange="Callingerrormesage()"
        MaximumNumberOfFiles="5" OnClientUploadComplete="File_Upload" />
```

Here is my script code:

```
<scrpt>
    function Callingerrormesage(){
        alert(1);
    }
</script>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string filename = e.FileName;
    string strDestPath = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/");
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(@strDestPath + filename);        
}
```

when I uploaded the `jpeg` file it's working fine when I need to upload the other than the jpeg file
I need to show the error message like

I had given `Onchange="Callingerrormesage()"` not working could you please help me on this?

Comment: there is a method called e.extention("jpg","JPeg").you can use

Comment: Thanks for reply  about this e.extention("jpg","JPeg") can u provide me some sample please

Answer (score 0):

You should validate BEFORE uploading like this:

```
$("input:file").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() !== "") {
        var ul_file = $(this).val();
        var extension = ul_file.substr((ul_file.lastIndexOf('.') + 1));
        var accepted_file_endings = ["jpg", "jpeg"];
        extension = extension.toLowerCase()
        if ($.inArray(extension, accepted_file_endings) !== -1) {
        ...
        //send file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
string filename = e.FileName;
string strFileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(strLongFilePath);
if(strFileExtension=="jpg")
{
Your code here
}
else
{
session["error"]="Your error message";
}
```

and retrive the session value at your page...

Comment: thanks for reply your  code works on button click but i am  looking for when the user selects the file like Onchange function if you  can help me on that please help thank you